# "Fix this prettier problem" formats code in VSCode, but then once I type the code reverts to previous formatting

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier-eslint

I get shown that my code does not have the correct formatting, and click on the red line that shows up. It gives the option to "fix this problem", and it will! But then as soon as I type again, the code reverts back to the formatting that was there prior to the "fix" and the red line shows up again.

I have prettier as my default formatter and believe it's set up.

Comment: possibly related (recent-found bug with Quick Fixes): https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/180721